# Find the Largest integer that is smaller than this expression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Largest integer that is smaller than

## $\frac{2^{2^{2021}}}{(2^{2^1}-2^{2^0}+1)(2^{2^2}-2^{2^1}+1)...(2^{2^{2020}}-2^{2^{2019}}+1)}$

is...

**My Progress**

### $\frac{1}{2^{2^{k+1}}-2^{2^k}+1}=\frac{2^{2^k}+1}{2^{3.2^k}+1}$

Reorder so

### $\frac{2^{2^{2021}}}{(2^{2^1}-2^{2^0}+1)(2^{2^2}-2^{2^1}+1)...(2^{2^{2020}}-2^{2^{2019}}+1)}$=$\prod_{i=0}^{2018}\frac{2^{2^{k+1}}}{2^{3.2^{k}}+1}.\frac{3.2^{2^{2021}}}{2^{3.2^{2019}}}< \frac{3.2^{2^{2021}}}{2^{3.2^{2019}}}$

I'm stuck here :(

If someone was able to finish this, that would be great, I've been looking for the answer for more than 1 hour:(

Comment: *Use smaller numbers* as test cases. Then look to generalize. It's extremely, extremely often the case that small instances, at least in elementary number theory, provide intuition for larger instances. You will drown in cancellations if you start with the big number, but for smaller numbers you will both cancel easily as well as see patterns which are generalizable to larger cases. Keep this in mind for future questions : in this particular case, the trick is to think about an appropriate "difference of squares" cascade.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it may be from an ongoing contest

Comment: this question is from finished contest, https://drive.google.com/file/d/103PWp0zY-bAGQtF8dbsBI017XWVb5OAJ/view?usp=sharing, question no. 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step is, good.

Then use:

$$(x-1)\prod_{k=0}^n \left(x^{2^k}+1\right)=x^{2^{n+1}}-1 $$

Prove by induction.

Use it with $x=2,x=2^3.$

Then $$\begin{align}\frac1{\prod_{k=0}^{2019}\left(2^{2^{k+1}}-2^{2^k}+1\right)}&=\prod_{k=0}^{2019}\frac{2^{2^k}+1}{2^{3\cdot 2^k}+1} \\
&=(8-1)\frac{2^{2^{2020}}-1}{2^{3\cdot 2^{2020}}-1}
\end{align}$$

So $$\begin{align}\frac{2^{2^{2021}}}{\prod_{k=0}^{2019}\left(2^{2^{k+1}}-2^{2^k}+1\right)}&=7\cdot\frac{2^{3\cdot 2^{2020}}-2^{2\cdot 2^{2020}}}{2^{3\cdot2^{2020}}-1}\\
&=7\cdot\left(1-\frac{4^{2^{2020}}-1}{8^{ 2^{2020}}-1}\right)\end{align}$$

And that fraction is much smaller than $\frac17,$ so the greatest integer is $6.$

---

More generally, $$\frac{x^{2^n}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(x^{2^{k+1}}-x^{2^k}+1\right)}=(x^2+x+1)\left(1-\frac{x^{2^{n}}-1}{x^{3\cdot 2^{n-1}}-1}\right)$$

Also when $x>1,$ $$\frac{x^{2^n}-1}{x^{3\cdot 2^{n-1}}-1}=\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}+1}{x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n-1}}+1}<\frac{1}{x^{2^{n-1}}}$$

In particular, for $x>1$ an integer and $n>2,$ the greatest integer would always be $x^2+x.$

When $n=2$ we have:

$$\frac{x^4}{x^2-x+1}=x^2+x-\frac{x}{x^2-x+1}$$

So the greatest integer is $x^2+x-1$ in that case.